# npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access

Tags: node.js, macos

I have been trying to fix the issue of running node without using sudo on my mac but I keep getting this message:

`npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/myuser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm`

And still find no fix for that. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 10):

This is a known bug, even now with `npm 6.14` available.
Here it is a link to [npm.community](https://npm.community/t/checkpermissions-missing-write-access-with-file-dependency/2922).

You can give current user permission to access node_modules using this in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and then `npm install`.

Answer (score 4):

OK I found what was wrong.
I tried to open the `/Users/myuser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm` folder on finder to see if I could change the folder permissions but it seemed like the npm folder was pointing to some non-existing directory.
So I removed the npm symbolic link and created a new empty npm folder and everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Ubuntu:

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.