# create-react-app newproject commandline is not working for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

for some reason ive been ending up with "command not found" when i type in the create-react-app newproject command. Its been giving me this error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! path /Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kennyquach/.npm/_logs/2018-11-28T17_50_32_739Z-debug.log
```

any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135281/npm-warn-checkpermissions-missing-write-access)

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly shows you dont have write access to `/Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app`

try changing access to 777 for all of .npm-global folders and then give a try.

Comment: hi, how to change access to 777? Sorry im fairly new

Comment: if you are in unix or linuxish systems (aka mac) you can use `chmod` command.. in windows you better right click on folder, under security tab look for  advanced button, you should be able to change the permissions there if you have access.

Comment: This is what i get:        usage: chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
 chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...

Comment: doing `man chmod` will show you how to use the command. if you want to blindly give persmission all the folders recursively, you can try `chmod -R 777 *`

Answer (score 1):

You are high likely using Mac OS as Operating System. This is a general issue of globally installed packages in MacOS that caused by built-in node application's file permissions. Actually you can get over this by executing `create-react-app` as **root**, but i don't recommend that, it's not useful and it's risky.

So you got 2 options. (First one is hard to do, second is blazing fast)

1-) Completely remove Node from your System and install it with **Brew**. You can easily update node with that package manager and install any other popular developer tools too (Like: mongodb, mysql, pgsql, rabbitmq etc.).
You can get brew from here: https://brew.sh and install node with that code: `brew install node`

2-) You can easily give read, write, execute access to your folders and files. You can do it like this: `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/kennyquach/.npm-global/` when sudo asks your password, use your Administrator password.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I went with the second option and entered the create-react-app line again. This time, no error, however i cant see the package installed anywhere

Comment: Hi, your welcome, What do you mean by "I can't see the package installed anywhere" I don't get it.

Comment: Like after I put "create-react-app newproject", I dont see the package in the folder

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an access issue. I faced same issue in MAC OS X, when I tried running the command with sudo, it worked for me.

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

Comment: please take your time to add a comment on how your answer would solve the op's issue. Code without comments is not valuable